# How to style error messages validated by Yup in a React Formik app?

Tags: css, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I'm building a form in React using Formik and Yup. I'm not sure on how to style the dynamic error messages that appear for the email and password fields. Below is a code sample:

https://codesandbox.io/s/j3l5w70q9w

[image]

I want to stylize the background colors, position and text colors but I don't know how to insert a custom class name into the error text that appears.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Oops nevermind, I got it...embarassingly.

You can style the error messages directly in the form:

```
   <p class="styles">{errors.email}</p>
```

My bad!

Answer (score 2):

The solution is clever but misleading.  Changing the class name to reflect what it is you are styling would be a lot clearer.  May I suggest:

```
<div class="error">{errors.email}</div>
```

Also, if you are using Formik, this works:

```
<div class='error'>
    <ErrorMessage name="details" />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.error {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: var(--red-600);
   margin-top: 0.25rem;
 }
```

Note: I prefer divs when the primary purpose of the tag is to style the contents, but that is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that you need to modify `class` to `className`

```
<p className="styles">{errors.email}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

/* RowWrapper and InputMask are components */

```
<RowWrapper className='hideDesk'>
   <InputMask 
      inputMask={masks.card}
      inputMode="numeric"
      guide={false}
      id="ccNumber"
      onFocus={focusChange}
      name="number"
      value={data.number}
      placeholder=""
      onChange={onChange}
    />
</RowWrapper>
```

/* Component Style */

```
export const RowWrapper = styled.div`
  span {
      font-size: 13px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: red
    }
```

/* Styled.div is a component, you can create that using like .div or .p whatever, is not important and depends on project, I'm explaining to make the code understand better   */